# having issues when extracting char values, using unsafe char* in a struct []

Tags: c#, arrays, string, character, unsafe

in this code i am trying to simulate a task that populats an array of structs,
...unsafe to get as much throughoutput as can be achived.

the issue is that i when calling the fucntion and itterating on the result
shows different characters but within the scope of `GetSomeTs()` it's fine.

so just before the return i test one of the elements and it prints the correct value.

this is the testing struct.

```
public unsafe struct T1
{
    public char* block = stackalloc char[5];<--will not compile so the process will be done within a local variable inside a method
}

public unsafe struct T1
{
    public char* block;
}

    static unsafe T1[] GetSomeTs(int ArrSz)
    {
        char[] SomeValChars = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
        T1[] RtT1Arr = new T1[ArrSz];

        for (int i = 0; i < RtT1Arr.Length; i++)
        {
            char* tmpCap = stackalloc char[5];

            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
            {
                SomeValChars[4] = i.ToString()[0];
                tmpCap[l] = SomeValChars[l]; 
            }


            RtT1Arr[i].block = tmpCap;//try 1
            //arr[i].block = &tmpCap[0];//try 2
        }
           // here its fine
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", new string(RtT1Arr[1].block)); 
        return RtT1Arr;
    }
```

but using it anywhere else printing garbage.

```
void Main()
{
     T1[] tstT1 = GetSomeTs(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", new string(tstT1[i].block));//,0,5, Encoding.Default));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate memory with `stackalloc` that memory only exists until the function returns in which you have allocated it. You are returning a pointer to memory that is no longer allowed to be accessed.

Hard to recommend a fix because it's unclear what you want to achieve. Probably, you should just use a managed `char[]`.

`Encoding.Default.GetBytes` is pretty slow so that's likely to be your hotspot anyway and the rest is less important. `i.ToString()` also is quite slow and produces garbage. If you are after perf then stop creating unneeded objects all the time such as `SomeValChars`. Create it once and reuse.

Comment: first thanks for your answer, and if i try to copy the result to manged char[] before exiting, via array copy i will loose the whole consept of doing it fast, cause it will be another task that consume time so better stay with char[] from begining?, the purpose of this code is to initialise an array of structs with values as fast as possible the idle type would be string, i am trying to gain performance vs the normal List<string>

Comment: Do you understand that the stackalloc approach has no chance of working because the memory is gone when the method returns?

Comment: i do, that is a rule by design , though not if you copy the block ..say `T1.block` is char[]  and i bother to go to unmanaged code as in the function `GetSomeTs()` all the same but in the end i will somehow (need to study casting `char*` to `char[]`) thus copy the content of tmpCap... it will sustain the value outside of GetSomeTs() though did i gain anything through all the process vs `char[]`= `char[]` or `string` = `string`, is the real question

Comment: So, ask yourself where you are going to copy to. Using stackalloc can only slow you down here by introducing a needless intermediate buffer.

Comment: You can't cast from pointer to array. An array is a full object that also stores a length. It's more than a pointer. The right way forward is to allocate an array in the first place, fill it and return it.

Comment: I think you should implement the perf suggestions that I made. They have 10x more impact than avoiding this array allocation.

Comment: am working on a new model using unsafe ... interop to dll  c++ using pointers, see if i get any change

Comment: @usr, hey i think i got the best solution, please could you find the time and comment on this posted answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219095/faster-way-to-return-data-as-an-array-interoping-c?answertab=active#tab-top