# compiler x86_64-w64-mingw32 complains on a code that was running fine

Tags: c++, malloc, dev-c++

the issue is after formatting windows (7 ultimate x64) I have tried to compile with new installation of `Dev C++` IDE using mingw32 that's all..
I wonder how typical is this and is it my fault ?

I have tried searching on this issue and not clear from very few results what could be the problem .

> ...\DevCpp\DevCPPDLLcpp.o DevCPPDLLcpp.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined
>   reference to `_imp__CoTaskMemAlloc@4'

the code is here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33238812/1329184

**EDIT:** added makefile..

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc -m32
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = DevCPPDLL.dll
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -m32 -DBUILDING_DLL=1
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -m32 -DBUILDING_DLL=1
RM       = rm.exe -f
DEF      = libDevCPPDLL.def
STATIC   = libDevCPPDLL.a

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN) $(DEF) $(STATIC)

$(BIN): $(LINKOBJ)
    $(CPP) -shared $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS) -Wl,--output-def,$(DEF),--out-implib,$(STATIC),--add-stdcall-alias
```

Comment: This is not a compiler error, but a linker error. You're not linking Ole32 any more apparently

Comment: This looks like a linking failure. Make sure that you're linking with the right libraries.

Comment: As already mentioned by @Voo, you need ole32.lib to be linked. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @rkosegi I have no idea how to, going through my code from the compilation with windows or gcc I could see `#include <stdio.h>` + `#include <OleAuto.h>`

Comment: @rkosegi it's `unmanaged c++` rather msvc++, note that I am new so I couldn't know if and how you realize it or not

Comment: @LoneXcoder from given snippet, I don't see content of $(LIBS), could you try to add  -lole32  to gcc's command line?

Comment: @rkosegi I have installed Intel `c++` restarting the whole intention of who to not deal with, stick to what I know works...(btw, it was the problem but only one that got me started to think I'm over it)